# Most efficient bubble sort mechanism

Tags: c#, sorting

I used some of my spare time to code a Little sorting mechanism: a bubble sort mechanism, here is what I came up with:

```
public class BubbleSort
{
    private bool _numbersAreSorted = false;

    public float[] Sort(float[] _list)
    {
        float num1;
        float num2;

        while (!_numbersAreSorted)
        {
            _numbersAreSorted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < _list.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                num1 = _list[i];
                num2 = _list[i + 1];
                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    _list[i] = num2;
                    _list[i + 1] = num1;
                    i--;
                    _numbersAreSorted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return _list;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it isn't something fancy, but it gets the Job done. What my question is: is this an 'efficient' way of programming a bubble sorting mechanism, or can I make some improvements?

Comment: This question should belongs to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, why reinvent the wheel? use a List and just Sort() it or use Array.Sort()...

Comment: I have written this as part for something bigger. I Need a base sorting mechanism to build on, to expand a bit with my own Little functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public float[] Sort(float[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < list.Length; j++) {
                if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
                {
                    float temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[i + 1];
                    list[i+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        } 

        return list;
    }
```

Some remarks:

- Don't reinvent the wheel and make your code very readable and your intent clear
- I don't think your bubble code implementation is actually O(N^2), could be larger due to the while loop